# Cursor Size Zero After Deleting First Item in Android SQLite Databse

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I have a SQLite database in my app that stores favorite items (Wallpapers) in it. I'm beginning to learn database management so most of this is new to me. However, I've managed to get the basic database working including adding, removing, and querying...except querying needs a little work.

Basically, the user opens an activity that has an image in it. They open a menu item which adds the current image to the database (using string values since the image is retrieved from the internet).

Next, I've got a special fragment which lists the favorites. When you long press on an item in said list, it'll be removed from the database.

Here's my problem: deleting items works fine except when I delete the 1st  item in the database. For some reason, that causes my cursor in getFavorite() to become zero and I get an exception.

See my code below...kind of a lot but I'm hoping someone can help me!

## Code

**SQLite Database Helper**

```
public class FavoritesHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favoritesManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_FAVORITES = "favoriteWallpapers";
    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_FILENAME = "file_name";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_URL, KEY_FILENAME};

    public FavoritesHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FAVORITES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_URL + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_FILENAME + " TEXT" + ");";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVORITES + ";");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addFavorite(Favorite favorite) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_URL, favorite.getURL()); // Favorite URL
        values.put(KEY_FILENAME, favorite.getFilename()); // Favorite Filename

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_FAVORITES, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public Favorite getFavorite(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_FAVORITES, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        KEY_URL, KEY_FILENAME}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // line 74
        return new Favorite(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    }

    public ArrayList<Favorite> getAllFavorites() {
        ArrayList<Favorite> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FAVORITES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
                favorite.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                favorite.setURL(cursor.getString(1));
                favorite.setFilename(cursor.getString(2));
                favoriteList.add(favorite);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return favoriteList;
    }

    public int getFavoritesCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FAVORITES + ";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }

    public void deleteFavorite(Favorite favorite) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_FAVORITES, " id  = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(favorite.getID())});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**Favorite Class**

```
public class Favorite {

    int _ID;
    String _URL;
    String _FILENAME;

    public Favorite() {
    }

    public Favorite(int ID, String URL, String Filename) {
        this._ID = ID;
        this._URL = URL;
        this._FILENAME = Filename;
    }

    public Favorite(String URL, String Filename) {
        this._URL = URL;
        this._FILENAME = Filename;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return _ID;
    }

    public void setID(int _ID) {
        this._ID = _ID;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return _URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String _URL) {
        this._URL = _URL;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return _FILENAME;
    }

    public void setFilename(String _FILENAME) {
        this._FILENAME = _FILENAME;
    }
}
```

**Custom Image Adapter in Favorites fragment**

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        FavoritesHandler favoritesHandler = new FavoritesHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        return favoritesHandler.getFavoritesCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder gridViewImageHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.util_grid_item_image, parent, false);
            gridViewImageHolder = new ViewHolder();
            gridViewImageHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.util_wallpaper_image);
            view.setTag(gridViewImageHolder);
        } else {
            gridViewImageHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        FavoritesHandler db = new FavoritesHandler(getActivity());

        List<Favorite> favorites = db.getAllFavorites();

        for (Favorite favorite : favorites) {
            favorite = db.getFavorite(position + 1);

            // line 136
            imageLoader.displayImage(favorite.getURL() + favorite.getFilename(),
                    gridViewImageHolder.imageView,
                    ImageLoaderUtil.setupOptions());
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Exception AFTER deleting first item in displayed list**

```
09-27 02:04:38.641 30338-30338/? E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 30338
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hidden.hidden.FavoritesHandler.getFavorite(FavoritesHandler.java:74)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hidden.hidden.fragments.FavoritesFragment$ImageAdapter.getView(FavoritesFragment.java:136)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-27 02:04:40.195 30338-30338/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've been working on trying to find a solution for this for about 3 days now...I think it needs a set of new eyes.

**Edit**

Added line numbers.

Comment: whats at FavoritesHandler.java:74 can you please edit and remove out all but the essential code and the essential bits of the stack trace

Comment: @e4c5 - I've updated my question with the line numbers labeled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I see your posted code and exception. It seems like the problem is due to of the index goes out of index. In your adapter the problem is the getCount() method of adapter and inside the getView(..)method See below I had update your adapter code.

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Favorite> favorites = new ArrayList();
    private FavoritesHandler db;

    public ImageAdapter(){
        db = new FavoritesHandler(getActivity());
        favorites.addAll(db.getAllFavorites());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return favorites.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder gridViewImageHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            gridViewImageHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.util_grid_item_image, parent, false);
            gridViewImageHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.util_wallpaper_image);
            view.setTag(gridViewImageHolder);
        } else {
            gridViewImageHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

         Favorite favorite = favorites.gePosition(position);
    imageLoader.displayImage(favorite.getURL() + favorite.getFilename(),gridViewImageHolder.imageView,ImageLoaderUtil.setupOptions());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any problem into it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is caused by you trying to fetch the non - existent element you just deleted.

```
favorite = db.getFavorite(position + 1);
```

This will query for the deleted item when the position is 0 again.

```
if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

This will make your code fail, because you are querying for the deleted item. This return an empty cursor, which is not `null`, but trying to move to the first resulting row causes the IndexOutOfBounds exception.

The general mistake you are making is that you are tying your item list position with their id, which is a bad practice. The way you present items for the user should be independent of their database representation.

If I may provide you with some more pointers:

- Your Adapter implementation is quite ineffective. You are hitting the database multiple times - once to find the count, once for each item you are presenting for the user. This can be avoided if you use either a CursorAdapter or, maybe a Loader, that fetches the list of favourites for you and creates some sort of custom ArrayAdapter instance.
- You should definitely consider moving DB access off the main thread, just to be on the safe side with performance.

Comment: Thanks for the consrtuctive criticism! I'll look into making this more effective.

Comment: I recommend you also check out `ContentProviders` to further your knowledge in using SQLite in Android. The examples are quite well written and they emphasise on best practices. Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to make here.

First, one problem lies in the construction of your `getFavorite()` method.

This method takes an `int` argument that specifies the `KEY_ID` of the row you want to retrieve from your cursor. As such, each time `getFavorite()` is called, it returns just one row of your database. When you call this method in `getView()`, you pass `position + 1` as its argument. As this row no longer exists in your database (because the `_id` column autoincrements, and the first row is position `(0 + 1)`) your `Cursor` will come back empty, and thus you will get an error if you try to access it.

To resolve it, do not call `db.getAllFavorites()` or `db.getFavorite()` in `getView()`. In addition to it being a very bad idea from a performance perspective to constantly runs queries in this way, the `KEY_ID` and row number of a `Cursor` do not always align exactly anyway. For example, imagine there is a `Cursor` with three entries:

```
_id    name
1      Cheddar
2      Parmesan
3      Brie
```

If you delete the row with the `KEY_ID` value of `1`, then calling `getCount()` on your cursor will say it has two entries. However, if you try to `query()` your database with a `KEY_ID` of `1`, then you will return an empty cursor (no results). What you instead what to access is **row number one of your cursor**, not the `_id`.

To achieve this, you need to `query()` your database outside of `getView()`, store the returned `Cursor` to a variable, and either use **that** to populate your list items directly, or write it to some form of `List` and use the `List` instead. Your `getAllFavorites()` method appears to do this, so you should use the `ArrayList` returned from this to populate your lists.

Be sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter as well once you have made any changes to the data used to populate your adapter (for example, after a delete).

I have written a [couple of blog posts](http://partisanapps.com/2015/08/really-useful-notes-saving-and-loading-with-a-local-database-i/), with source code and a sample app, on the topic of SQLite databases in Android, which go into more detail if you are interested.

A final point worth mentioning is that you could improve your methods with respect to performance. Database operations in Android are slow, and as a result you want to call methods that interact with them directly, like `query()`, as few times as possible. The ideal scenario is that a database is queried once, and then all further operations are on the returned `cursor`. If the data changes in your database in a significant way, then again query it once and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Currently, the your are calling `getAllFavorites()`, which queries your entire database, every time `getView()` is called (which is essentially whenever your list is scrolled). Then, even though `getAllFavorites()` returns all the information you require several times over, each entry is needlessly overriden by calling `getFavorite()`. In addition, large `query()` calls should occur off the main thread, otherwise they can lock the UI for several seconds. `AsyncTasks` are good for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I did what Bhavdip suggested above and that fixed things.